# should .RData files be used to store functions?

Tags: r, rdata

I use .RData files to store objects (e.g. lists, vectors, etc) then call them into other scripts, but I'm wondering whether they should also be used to store functions (most likely user-defined functions)?

I know `source()` is generally recommended for this purpose (and creating `packages` even more so), but an advantage as I see it is that a single .RData file can contain multiple objects - a list, dataframe, and the function, for example. Saves needing to call objects using `load()`, then the function separately, using `source()`.

Are there reasons to be cautious of this approach, that I'm not seeing?

Thank you

Comment: I don't know that you will be denied any basic functionality of functions (e.g., capability to debug and see the functions' source), but I also don't know what it'll buy you. Storing them in packages is very easy, allows simple in-source comments to be converted into man-pages (via `roxygen2`), and many other benefits.

Comment: I don't see any real harm in it, but no advantage either. You should, of course, keep the source code somewhere for both the functions and the objects. The advantage of using RData files for objects is that some objects can take a lot of time to compute/define, but functions don't have that issue so there is no real advantage. If you find this tempting because 2 commands, `load` and `source`, is too many, I'd instead encourage you to keep a small loading script that does all the loading and sourcing. Then, sourcing that single script performs everything.

Comment: That way you can also further break down your objects and such into smaller, better organized pieces, all of which are loaded in the correct order by the loading script.

Comment: Extension says `.RData`, no harm keeping function in there, but happy place for functions is a package or `.R` file with `source()`. Besides when we want to use only the functions in other new data, we will then have to load old data we don't need.

Answer (score 0):

At my old job, we used to serialize out closures:

```
> f <- (function(x) function() x)(2)
> f()
[1] 2
> saveRDS(f, file='/tmp/f')
```

and then

```
> f <- readRDS('/tmp/f')
> f()
[1] 2
```

This can let you bundle data (eg coefficients) with a function. Be careful though, your libraries won't get autoloaded.